# Programmr "Reverse Array" C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I use **Programmr.com** to improve my skills. I have a problem with this exercise.

> Question:
>
> Write the program which takes input 10 elements in the array and
>   reverse the elements in the array without using any other array.
>
> Example :
>   1.If user gives input 1,2,3,4,5,5,4,7,3,6 then output should be in this format: 6 3 7 4 5 5 4 3 2 1
>
> 2.If user gives input 25,23,,26,12,45,65,58,24,27,13 then output should be in this format: 13 27 24 58 65 45 12 26 23 25
>
> Note : Make sure the output format is same as above given example.

My code:

```
using System;
class ReverseArray{
   static void Main(string[] args){

        int[] arr = new int[10];

         for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
         {
          Console.WriteLine("Enter the array elements["+i+"]:");
          arr[i]=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         } 
          //write your logic here

        for(int i = arr.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
          Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
        }
          //end 

         for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
         {
         Console.Write(arr[i]+" ");
         }
}
}
```

Programmr doesn't pass task and write that there are **undefined errors**. I also tried method **Array.Reverse**.

Comment: What is the question?  Programming exercises are not questions.

Comment: @LVBen Where is my fault? I cannot find error.

Comment: The input is not clear. Does the input actually contain commas? You aren't handling them in any way.

Comment: You are printing both the reversed and the initial array contents to the console, which the question doesn't seem to call for. Regardless, your question isn't clear - you aren't actually creating a reversed array in place, which the title seems to call for, instead you're iterating the existing array in reverse order, which seems to meet the needs of generating the output, but it's not clear if this meets the needs of whatever test harness is being used to validate logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Linq reverse method and string.join

You can:

```
Using System.Linq; 

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", arr.Reverse()));
```

That will reverse the array and print the list separated by spaces to the console

Comment: This would be too painfully slow for any real-world, performant-critical use.

Comment: Of course performance is not a priority in this case, the max size of his array is 10